# Java script closing my pop up window on button click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to close my pop up window. I can only do this within my javascript file. I am having trouble with it and It isn't working. Here is my code. My pop up window works, without the close button function.

```
var addbuttonclicked = document.querySelector('#sell-something-button');

addbuttonclicked.addEventListener('click', function()
{
    document.getElementById("sell-something-modal").classList.remove('hidden');
    document.getElementById("modal-backdrop").classList.remove('hidden');
});

// When close is clicked this window should be closed

var closebutton = document.querySelector('#close-modal');

closebutton.addEventListener('click', function()
{
    window.close()
}
```

Comment: window is the browser window.... you are trying to close the browser? Or are you trying to hide the element you showed above?

Comment: I am trying to hide the element I showed above. It is like a pop up that displays in the browser and I need to close it if the close button "modal-close" is clicked

Comment: So you need to add the things you removed! :) window.close() is trying to close the browser/tab.... so what do you think needs to happen when you did this: `.classList.remove('hidden');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just mark it as hidden again.

```
var addbuttonclicked = document.querySelector('#sell-something-button');
    addbuttonclicked.addEventListener('click', function(){
        document.getElementById("sell-something-modal").classList.remove('hidden');
        document.getElementById("modal-backdrop").classList.remove('hidden');    
});

//When close is clicked this window should be closed
var closebutton = document.querySelector('#close-modal');
closebutton.addEventListener('click', function(){    
   document.getElementById("sell-something-modal").classList.add('hidden');
   document.getElementById("modal-backdrop").classList.add('hidden');
});
```

Comment: When I add this, my first button that adds the pop-up window doesn't work. Any suggestions? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @AndrewWhite this would be much easier if could see what you are talking about. Do you have a link to the site or a codepen I could look at?

Comment: I actually just needed to add the parenthese and the ; after the closing bracket on the end! This worked perfectly! Thank you for the help.

Comment: No problem.Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

```
var addbuttonclicked = document.querySelector('#sell-something-button');
addbuttonclicked.addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.getElementById("sell-something-modal").classList.remove('hidden');
    document.getElementById("modal-backdrop").classList.remove('hidden');
});

//When close is clicked this window should be closed
var closebutton = document.querySelector('#close-modal');
closebutton.addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.getElementById("sell-something-modal").classList.add('hidden');
    document.getElementById("modal-backdrop").classList.add('hidden');
}
```

Comment: When I add this, my first button that adds the pop-up window doesn't work. Any suggestions? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sure. Wanna create a codepen or jsfiddle with your code and I'll be happy to troubleshoot for ya :)